# Can't make a post call in react

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs

I'm learning react and I have started by creating a CRUD app in react. I am able to make the get calls but the post calls don't go through for some reason. My App.js file is:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import $ from 'jquery'
import request from "../node_modules/superagent/superagent";
import axios from 'axios'

import {UserForm} from './components/userForm'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      name: '',
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
    this.handlePostRequest = this.handlePostRequest.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(state, event) {
    this.setState({[state]: event.target.value});
  }

  handlePostRequest(event) {
    var data = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }

    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/users', {
      data: data
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

  /*request
  .post('http://localhost:8080/api/users')
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  .send({ name: this.state.name, email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password })
  .end(function(err, res){
  console.log(res.text);
  });
    var self

    event.preventDefault()
    self = this

    console.log(this.state);

    var data = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }

    // Submit form via jQuery/AJAX
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/users',
      data: data
    })
    .done(function(result) {
      self.clearForm()
      this.setState({result:result})
    }).bind(this)
    .fail(function(jqXhr) {
      console.log('failed to add the user');
    }).bind(this)*/
    }

  componentDidMount() {
  this.App();
  }

  //making a get call
  App() {
    return $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/api/users')
      .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        this.setState({users:data});
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React CRUD App</h2>
        </div>
        <div className = "Crud-App" >

          <div className = "users-list" >
            <ul>
              {this.state.users.map( user => 
                <li key = {user._id} > 
                  {user.name} 
                </li> 
              )} 
            </ul>
          </div>

          <UserForm handleInputChange = {this.handleInputChange} name = {this.state.name} 
          email = {this.state.email} password = {this.state.password} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And my userForm component file is:

```js
import React from 'react'

export const UserForm = (props) => (
    <form>
        <label> Name: </label> <input onChange={props.handleInputChange.bind(this, 'name')} 
            value={props.name} />
        <label> Email: </label> <input type="text" onChange={props.handleInputChange.bind(this, 'email')} 
            value={props.email} />
        <label> Password: </label> <input type="text" onChange={props.handleInputChange.bind(this, 'password')} 
            value={props.password} />
        <button type="button" className = "pure-button pure-button-primary" onClick={props.handlePostRequest}>Add User</button>
    </form>
)
```

I have tried ajax, axios, superagent and fetch so far as you can see the commented code in the App.js file. But pressing the submit button does nothing at all. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stateless function components do not have a `this`. You should not re-bind the `onChange` handlers in your `UserForm` component.

Also, rewrite your handler signature so that it only takes the `event` argument:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.makeHandleInputChange = this.makeHandleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  makeHandleInputChange(state) {
    return e => {
      this.setState({[state]: event.target.value});
    };
  }
```

Lastly, update your usage of `UserForm`:

```
<UserForm
  makeHandleInputChange={this.makeHandleInputChange}
  name={this.state.name} 
  email={this.state.email}
  password={this.state.password} />
```

and the definition of `UserForm` itself:

```
export const UserForm = (props) => (
  <form>
    <label> Name: </label>
    <input
      onChange={props.makeHandleInputChange('name')} 
      value={props.name} />
    { /* ...the rest of the components here... */ }
  </form>
)
```

**EDIT: You are not passing the `handlePostRequest` as a prop to the `UserForm`.**

```
<UserForm
  makeHandleInputChange={this.makeHandleInputChange}
  handlePostRequest={this.handlePostRequest}
  name={this.state.name} 
  email={this.state.email}
  password={this.state.password} />
```

Comment: Without binding it throws an error saying "cannot read property 'target' of undefined"

Comment: The event handler is only called with the `event` argument, you should pass a handler with the correct signature. See edit.

Comment: I made the suggested changes but the post call still doesn't work. When I type data  into the form fields, the state changes correctly but the post call that I have written doesn't work for some reason, i.e. pressing the "Add User" button doesn't send a post call

Comment: See final edit. You're never pass the `handlePostRequest` prop to the `UserForm` component. :)

Comment: Thanks mate. Works like a charm. :)